# Is there any Efficient way to display lots of labels in form?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have a GUI Program, that creates labels containing names of files  according to the search query provided by the user at runtime and displays them. The no of labels displayed can vary considerably based on the user input.
The no can vary between 0 to 2000(approx) . When the no of labels exceed 1000 or so, the time taken for the form in which the labels are contained takes a lot of time to display.
The time taken to display the form completely outweighs the  time saved in making a good algorithm(for some cases)!. I am looking for an efficient way so that I can display the form easily in less amount of time. Currently, It takes 1minute 45 seconds to display a form containing 1499 Labels.
Currently , I am doing like this:-

```
    foreach(string Elements in FileList)
    {
      Label LabelA = new Label() ; 
      // other code here to modify the appearence of label
      LabelA.Show() ;
    }
     MyForm.Show();
    // File List is the List of file names which are to be displayed.
    //MyForm is the name of the form in which labels are added at runtime.
```

Comment: Have you explored other control types, things like grids or list boxes, things that are designed for multiple items?

Comment: Is there a particular reason why you're creating the data as Label objects? Why not use something like a ListView to display the files?

Comment: @Joe EnosNo, I haven't explored them

Comment: Did you try `Form.DoubleBuffered = true` or `Form.SuspendLayout()` and `Form.ResumeLayout()`?

Comment: @AndyNo, I didn't knew about all these

Comment: Ideally, I'd modify your form design to implement some form of pagination or something similar to ensure only a given number are displayed at any given time. If this makes sense from a usability perspective, then definitely do it. It will also obviously benefit performance as your GUI is only rendering a set number of controls.

Comment: If these labels are just stacked on top of each other, **why don't you just make one label, use a StgringBuilder to build your string, and stick it into the label?**

Comment: @MillieSmith Although the labels are on top of each other,I still want to make different labels because , I have added the click event to each label. I want to execute some process depending on which label you click .

Comment: Do hit detection yourself.

Comment: Figure out what x and y on the label is clicked, calculate what data is in that spot, and run your necessary code. It will blow the performance issues out of the water.

Comment: What is the reason for not using DataGridView? It has cell click events too. It may be a bit faster to build a DataTable and use it as the datasource rather than using an unbound grid. You can create a DataView from the DataTable for fast row filtering. e.g. add a textbox for the user to enter a search string and filter the rows shown.

Comment: @rheitzman I solved the problem by using ListBox instead of Labels

Answer (score 0):

There could be *at least* a couple of techniques:

- it's technically impossible that one can look on all of them contemporary, so solution is just devide them into `Tabs`. So divide them into groups of your application logic.
- defered scrolling. So when user scrolls the window, only the data inside them changed (and also corresponding data field)

Just to give an idea, but basically to invite attention to a simple fact that *you for sure* do need all that controls at once on UI. If these solutions are not ok, change control, so rapresentation of data.

Comment: To my problem it seems the defered scrolling remains the only solution, Can you please give an example of the implementation of defered scrolling, I have googled it but couldn't find any simple example.

Answer (score 0):

1. **Asyn get result**  Maybe you can use `BackGroundWorker` to asynchronously query the result and create the label. The way will give you a well user experience .
2. **Suspend then Resume** When you add the label you should use `Control.SuspendLayout()` and `Control.ResumeLayout()`
3. **Page the Result** Other way you can page for the result.

Comment: [How to: Use a Background Worker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc221403(v=vs.95).aspx),[Control.SuspendLayout Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.suspendlayout.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use labels with that create labels on program startup and add them a list for instant access to them

```
// create a list on there
List<Label> lblList = new List<Label>;
public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        for(int i = 0 ; i<1500;i++)
        {
          Label LabelA = new Label() ; 
          // other code here to modify the appearence of label
          LabelA.Show() ;
          lblList.Add(LabelA);
        }
    }
```

if you do this on a backGroundWorker your program will open fast and you can make a prograss bar for label creation. this will create labels and add them a list. You can access them with their indexes and change their text like that:

```
int index=0;
foreach(Label o in lblList)
{
    o.Text="Text";
    index++;//you can use this index if you want to know which label you editing
}
```

if you create labels on start up this will take some time but when you use them this way will be faster from creating them and values will display instantly.

Sorry for bad english.

Comment: Thanks for the extensive answer, but my problem is that the form takes too long to open, and this isn't solving my problem. I tried it.

Comment: @Pratik You can try add values to a richTextBox like value+"\n" they will display in lines or try listbox or combobox. I think listbox or richTextbox will solve your problem if you dont want to user change values you can set richTextbox to only read.Creating several labels will couse perfomance issues.